# Does $.ajax substitute $(document).ready(function()?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I 've made a thorough search, however I cannot find something clear about my assumption. I 've used the following code:

```
<?php  
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['valid_user']) && $_SESSION['from']==1)
{
 ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url:"user.php",
        success: function(newdata) {
             if (newdata == "nothing")
            {
               var temp1 ="no data!";
               $("#results_ribbon").text(temp1);              
               return;
            }
            var temp1 ="You have: ".concat(newdata);
            $("#results_ribbon").text(temp1); 
        }   
    });
  </script>
```

which is part of a php file. The HTML code which builds the DOM follows after the above code...

So, I'd expect div with id="results_ribbon" not to have the right content since #results_ribbon does not exist, yet. However, everything works fine. This led me to assume that $.ajax call waits to be executed after DOM loading. Am I right? If not why the above happens?

Comment: .ajax and .ready are two different functions, ajax does an ajax request, ready is for executing a function when the DOM has been fully loaded. it works because it takes time for a ajax request to finish (its async) so the DOM has had time to load. If you add `async:false` to the ajax options, it should then fail

Comment: Is requirement to "wait" until `$.ajax()` completes before calling `.ready()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not correct. Actual Ajax request starts immediately after your call it.
But success callback will fire after a while when it gets the server response.
By that time you already have your #results_ribbon loaded in DOM.

Comment: So, I cannot rely on it and as to be sure I have to use .ready, isn't  it?

Comment: Yep, just wrap you ajax call in $(function(){ // your code  }); . It is a snippet for $(document).ready();

Answer (score 1):

Ajax requests do not immediately return a result, there is a delay. This delay may or **may not** be long enough for your "results_ribbon" div to be created.

To be sure, just wrap the ajax call in `$(function(){ (...) });` which is shorthand for $(document).ready.